# Using ES6 syntax in Node script with Babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have an npm CLI tool that is using ES6 syntax from BabelJS. Specifically, I am using arrow functions from ES6.

In my entry point to the tool, I have the following require:

```
require('babel-core/register');
var program = require('./modules/program.js');
```

I also have a `.babelrc` file in root that looks like such:

```
{ "presets": ["es2015"] }
```

In this instance, `program.js` is where most of the heavy lifting is done. And in this file there is an arrow function like:

```
arrayOfStrings.forEach((substr) => {
    console.log(substr);
});
```

If I run this tool with the following command, it works just fine.

```
node index.js --options
```

However, if I publish this tool with `npm publish` and run it like so:

```
tool-name --options
```

I get this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/unfollow/modules/program.js:134
    arrayOfStrings.forEach((substr) => {
                             ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tool-name/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:138:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tool-name/index.js:7:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
```

Does anyone know why this could be?

Comment: FWIW, arrow functions are supported natively in Node v4+

Comment: @FelixKling interesting! so upgrading my node version did work, but I'm still curious why that failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`babel-register` is only meant to simplify local development, not for distributed packages. If you are making something for npm, you should compile it to ES5 beforehand.

Comment: You're right. You know when you read something and you realize your total mindset was wrong. This did that for me. Thanks, @loganfsmyth.